# Re-initializing Angular-slick directive

Tags: angularjs, slider

I am using the Angular-slick directive and I am having a tiny bit of a problem. I am sure that others may have had similar problems, but I hope someone out there can help me figure this out.

So I have a series of angular directives on my page. Each directive has properties that can be set in order to filter data in the other directives. My Angular-slick directive is bound to data that is coming from a Web API call. On the first load, the directive is perfect and it works fine. But once an action from one of the other directives causes the Angular-slick directive to filter its data (which is just another Web API call that returns similar data as the initial load), the entire the slider gets wacky and out of order. All the slides are displayed vertically.

Here is the code from the template:

```
<div id="slickContainer" ng-show="ctlr.SectionDataAvailable">
                <div id="slickSlider">
                    <div id="currentDateRange">
                        <span ng-bind="ctlr.ApiResult.CurrentDateRangeHeaderText"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="previousDateRange">
                        <span ng-bind="ctlr.ApiResult.PreviousDateRangeHeaderText"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="slick">
                        <slick init-onload="false"
                               data="ctlr.DataLoaded"
                               arrows="true"
                               slides-to-show="3"
                               slides-to-scroll="3"
                               infinite="false"
                               dots="false"
                               responsive="ctlr.SlickResponsive()">
                            <div ng-repeat="doubledUpResult in ctlr.ApiResult.DoubledUpResults" id="slickConatiner">

                                <!--Current Item-->
                                <div id="currentItemContainer">

                                    <div class="creative-item-heading-container"
                                         ng-show="doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.HasACreative">
                                        <span>{{doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.Headline}}</span><br />
                                        <div ng-show="doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.IsFirstOccurrenceVisible">
                                            <span style="color: #dd4f04;">First Occurrence: </span>
                                            <span>{{doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.FirstPropertyName}}</span>
                                            <span>{{doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.FirstCreativeDateText}}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div ng-show="doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.IsLastOccurrenceVisible">
                                            <span style="color: #dd4f04;">Last Occurrence: </span>
                                            <span>{{doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.LastPropertyName}}</span>
                                            <span>{{doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.LastCreativeDateText}}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div ng-show="doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.HasACreative">
                                            <span style="color: #dd4f04;">Total: </span>
                                            <span>
                                                {{doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.ActivityTotalText}}{{doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.ActivityFootnoteIndicator}}
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div ng-show="doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.IsAdvertiserVisible">
                                            <span style="color: #dd4f04;">{{doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.EntityTypeDescription}}:</span>
                                            <span>
                                                <a ng-click="ctlr.OnEntityLinkClicked(doubledUpResult.CurrentItem)">
                                                    {{doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.EntityName}}
                                                </a>
                                            </span>
                                            <span>{{doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.ExtraAdvertiserNote}}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="creative-thumbnail"
                                         ng-show="doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.HasACreative">
                                        <kmi-crv-thumbnail creative-id="doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.CreativeIdStr"
                                                           creative-type="doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.CreativeType"
                                                           size="ctlr.ThumbnailSize"
                                                           storage-provider="ctlr.StorageProvider"
                                                           base-path="'/KMI/IntelliDrive/ApplUI'"
                                                           style="margin: 0 auto; cursor:pointer;"
                                                           ng-click="ctlr.OnCreativeClicked(doubledUpResult.CurrentItem)"
                                                           is-delayed="'true'"></kmi-crv-thumbnail>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="creative-item-button-container"
                                         ng-show="doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.HasACreative">

                                        <a ng-click="ctlr.OnCreativeClicked(doubledUpResult.CurrentItem)"
                                           class="top-creatives-button current-item"
                                           ng-show="doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.IsQuickViewVisible"
                                           ng-style="ctlr.GetStyle(doubledUpResult.CurrentItem, 'QuickView')">Quick View</a>

                                        <a ng-click="ctlr.OnViewInLibraryClicked(doubledUpResult.CurrentItem)"
                                           class="top-creatives-button current-item"
                                           ng-show="doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.CanViewInLibrary"
                                           ng-style="ctlr.GetStyle(doubledUpResult.CurrentItem, 'ViewInLibrary')">View in Library</a>

                                        <a ng-click="ctlr.OnAddToCartClicked(doubledUpResult.CurrentItem)"
                                           class="top-creatives-button current-item"
                                           ng-show="doubledUpResult.CurrentItem.CanAddToShoppingCart"
                                           ng-style="ctlr.GetStyle(doubledUpResult.CurrentItem, 'AddToCart')">Add to Cart</a>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <!--Previous Item-->
                                <div id="previousItemContainer">

                                    <div class="creative-item-heading-container"
                                         ng-show="doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.HasACreative">
                                        <span>{{doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.Headline}}</span><br />
                                        <div ng-show="doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.IsFirstOccurrenceVisible">
                                            <span style="color: #dd4f04;">First Occurrence: </span>
                                            <span>{{doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.FirstPropertyName}}</span>
                                            <span>{{doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.FirstCreativeDateText}}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div ng-show="doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.IsLastOccurrenceVisible">
                                            <span style="color: #dd4f04;">Last Occurrence: </span>
                                            <span>{{doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.LastPropertyName}}</span>
                                            <span>{{doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.LastCreativeDateText}}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div ng-show="doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.HasACreative">
                                            <span style="color: #dd4f04;">Total: </span>
                                            <span>
                                                {{doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.ActivityTotalText}}{{doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.ActivityFootnoteIndicator}}
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div ng-show="doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.IsAdvertiserVisible">
                                            <span style="color: #dd4f04;">{{doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.EntityTypeDescription}}:</span>
                                            <span>
                                                <a ng-click="ctlr.OnEntityLinkClicked(doubledUpResult.PreviousItem)">
                                                    {{doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.EntityName}}
                                                </a>
                                            </span>
                                            <span>{{doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.ExtraAdvertiserNote}}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="creative-thumbnail"
                                         ng-show="doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.HasACreative">
                                        <kmi-crv-thumbnail creative-id="doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.CreativeIdStr"
                                                           creative-type="doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.CreativeType"
                                                           size="ctlr.ThumbnailSize"
                                                           storage-provider="ctlr.StorageProvider"
                                                           base-path="'/KMI/IntelliDrive/ApplUI'"
                                                           ng-click="ctlr.OnCreativeClicked(doubledUpResult.PreviousItem)"
                                                           style="margin: 0 auto; cursor:pointer;"
                                                           is-delayed="'true'"></kmi-crv-thumbnail>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="creative-item-button-container"
                                         ng-show="doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.HasACreative">

                                        <a ng-click="ctlr.OnCreativeClicked(doubledUpResult.PreviousItem)"
                                           class="top-creatives-button previous-item"
                                           ng-show="doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.IsQuickViewVisible"
                                           ng-style="ctlr.GetStyle(doubledUpResult.PreviousItem, 'QuickView')">Quick View</a>

                                        <a ng-click="ctlr.OnViewInLibraryClicked(doubledUpResult.PreviousItem)"
                                           class="top-creatives-button previous-item"
                                           ng-show="doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.CanViewInLibrary"
                                           ng-style="ctlr.GetStyle(doubledUpResult.PreviousItem, 'ViewInLibrary')">View in Library</a>

                                        <a ng-click="ctlr.OnAddToCartClicked(doubledUpResult.PreviousItem)"
                                           class="top-creatives-button previous-item"
                                           ng-show="doubledUpResult.PreviousItem.CanAddToShoppingCart"
                                           ng-style="ctlr.GetStyle(doubledUpResult.PreviousItem, 'AddToCart')">Add to Cart</a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </slick>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When the action from another directive is fired, all I want to do is make a Web API call, which brings back a new data set that the slider is then rebound to. My problem is I can't figure out how to do the rebinding without breaking the slider.

Thanks.